# Create Test Summary Data from influxdb and display in Grafana

Tags: influxdb, statsd, grafana

I'm considering deploying statsd, influxdb and grafana for collectin,storing and viewing time series data from performance tests.

I just want to know if out of the box grafana will let you generate summary data on performance counters from influxdb.

If no, is there something else that is designed specifically for doing this with data from influxdb?

Currently I can only find visual examples of mining data for time series graphs and not table summary data. I'm looking to generate a summary report on a specified time period in order to calculate a pass or fail for a performance test. I want to generate something like this:

[image: Performance Test Result Summary]

Comment: Sounds like single stat http://docs.grafana.org/reference/singlestat/

Comment: Thanks Mika. Singlestat looks different than the above sample table to me. Singlestat crams everything into one cell. I think that would be fine if I only had a handfull but I've got hundreds of these metrics. I'm not sure how I missed this when reviewing the grafana doc the first time but I now see grafana has something called table panel. The example in their doc shows time series data in each row but it looks like you could switch it to anything. http://docs.grafana.org/reference/table_panel/ .

Comment: I don't want to mark my own question answered unless I can answer it definitively by trying it (which will take me a while since I don't have it installed yet) or if someone else can confirm it can be used in this way I'd mark table panel as the right answer and accept it.